# How can we get the active/current model of the view in a JavaScript file of Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

How can we get the active/current model of the view in a js file of `Odoo 10`.
I have to do some codes based on the active model in `Odoo 10`.

Comment: please update your question with the code which you tried so far.